# Why my first "for" loop result appears when it doesn't match the result?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
foo = {('dying', 'dead', 'mourir', 'pass away'): ['A.Death','B.DDD'],('yyy', 'qe', 'tgg', 'ijg'):['KOH','TYH']}

key = 'tgg'
for k, v in foo.items():
    if key in k:
        print(v)
    else:
        print('no')
```

Output:

```
no
['KOH', 'TYH']
```

I thought the output supposes to be ['KOH', 'TYH'] ONLY, but why 'no' comes out?
How to fix it?
I hope it can be     ['KOH', 'TYH'] only

Comment: 'tgg' is not present in ('dying', 'dead', 'mourir', 'pass away') so no get's printed in else block.

Comment: So, is there any function to skip the first loop result? I only want     ['KOH', 'TYH']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foo = {('dying', 'dead', 'mourir', 'pass away'): ['A.Death','B.DDD'],('yyy', 'qe', 'tgg', 'ijg'):['KOH','TYH']}

key = 'tgg'

```
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(foo.items()):
    if i > 0:
        if key in k:
            print(v)
        else:
            print('no')
```

Comment: Thank you! But if i use 'dying' to find the first key-value, the output would show 'no'.

Comment: Should it be ['A.Death','B.DDD'] ?

Answer (score 0):

You loop over both dictionary entries.

`'tgg'` is not in `('dying', 'dead', 'mourir', 'pass away')` => `no`
`'tgg'` is in `('yyy', 'qe', 'tgg', 'ijg')` => `['KOH','TYH']`